# How to clear push notifications programmatically-iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

I need to clear push notifications from notification center after the user read them. I know there is cancelAllLocalNotifications method, but how do I clear all remote notifications?
As an addition I would like to have the following functionality, if user has 5 messages in notification center, we clear all notifications only after user reads All of them. Any ideas how these can be implemented? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to clear notifications in swift

```
import UserNotifications

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() // To remove all    pending notifications which are not delivered yet but scheduled.
    center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear them using `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber`, e.g.:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to remove the notifications from the Notification Center, it just removes the badge number.